# git remove commit on the server

Tags: git, git-reset

i've made some mistakes about my project managed in git:

reading some guides and some posts here I made this command:

```
git reset --hard a77ec5f
```

where the commint a77ec5f is the last 'good' commit

after this, the files are right in my local copy, but if I do a `git status`:

```
$ git status
# On branch dev
# Your branch is behind 'origin/dev' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

and now, how can I tell the server that the 4 commits that I'm behind are to remove?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your repository is synced by others, then you should not push any history changes unless you are certain nobody has pulled the bad changes yet.

To rewrite history (dangerous), do an empty commit locally (`git commit --allow-empty`) to diverge your HEAD from the remote HEAD, then `push --force` to rewrite the server's history.

Comment: the changes are in the server... how can I do the dummy commit?

Comment: Added a short description.

Comment: In most cases, rewrite history isn't a good choice. Be sure there is no other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you should not remove the commits on your server, but revert them

Comment: thanks, and at the point where I am, how can I 'jump' these 4 commits?

Comment: @marian-theisen: Could you tell how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can revert the unwanted commits.

```
git revert commit
```

This will create another commit that reverts the unwanted changes. After you revert the unwanted commit, you should push to origin.

You can look for `--no-commit` parameter for reverting also.