# Bitbucket: forgot to put data folder in gitignore. Now repos contains 1GB of temp storage data. How to clean it?

Tags: git, bitbucket

So, it's in the title pretty much.

The code creates a temp folder `Data` with loads of intermediate output in it.

I forgot to put that folder in `.gitignore`, then hit pushed to master and went to sleep. Now the repos is too big by about 1GB. How can I remove these files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16809273/5945883 ?

Comment: I have to ask the question of why the generated folder location is within the `.git` directory.  If it doesn't need to be there, then put it somewhere else.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: fair point and I have done so now. But how to get rid of that 1GB folder humpy-dumpying around on the repo?

Comment: I think you will need something like filter-branch.  Unless you recently made the bad commit, and rebasing is possible.